# How the mapping from power set of a set defined?

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

So sorry for such an easy and bad question....

In [Huber's paper](http://virtualmath1.stanford.edu/~conrad/Perfseminar/refs/Hubercontval.pdf)
page 462 , I can't understand how $P(A\times A)=\{0,1\}^{A \times A}$ is defined? Can some one please give an example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\mathscr{P}(A \times A)$ is just the set of all subsets of $A \times A$ (so in fact all relations on $A$; a relation on $A$ is precisely a subset of $A \times A$) and Huber wants to give this a topology: a standard identification that's often made is to associate a subset $R$ of $A \times A$ with its characteristic function $\chi_R: A \times A \to \{0,1\}$ defined by $$\chi_R((a,a')= \begin{cases} 1 & (a,a') \in R\\
0 & (a,a') \notin R\end{cases}$$

It's easy to see that $\mathscr{P}(A \times A)$ is in bijection with $\{0,1\}^{A \times A}$, where the latter is the set of all functions $A \times A \to \{0,1\}$. He sees the latter as a space in the product topology (where we have $A \times A$ many copies of $\{0,1\}$, as it were), and each $\{0,1\}$ is discrete.